# Normal distribution - finding X value given probability P(-x < X < x) = 0.95

Tags: normal-distribution, z-score, probability-calculus

I am learning statistics by myself online and I just encountered a problem that I am not able to solve.

$X \sim N(10, 4)$. I need to find $P(-x<X-10<x) = 0.95$. It resulted to the following $P(Z<x/2) - P(Z<-x/2) = 0.95$. How to find the x value? The answer sheet gave this  $x/2 = 1.96$ and $x = 3.92$ as a solution.
Can you help me decipher this simple problem?

Answer (score 3):

This figure will make the answer clear.

> [image]

Since we are trying to calculate the range of $Xs$ such that the area under the density curve of the distribution is $95\%$, we require that the remaining areas on both sides occupy $5\%$ in totality, which works out to $2.5\%$ on each side.

Since $X$ is $N(10,4)$, $X-10$ is $N(0,4)$. Then, using R, you can obtain the limits of $x$ using the `qnorm` command.

```
> qnorm(0.975,0,4)
[1] 7.839856
> qnorm(0.025,0,4)
[1] -7.839856
```

Hence, $x = \pm 7.83$.
You can adjust it to the $10$-centred distribution by adding $10$ to both the limits.

Comment: The illustration helps and shows your approach is basically correct.  In light of the *stated* answer in the question, though, it looks like we need to interpret "$N(0,4)$" as referring to a mean-zero Normal distribution with a *variance* of $4.$  Deserving of further explanation is the process used to reduce the problem to a *standard* Normal distribution: that clearly is the intent of the answer sheet. A more revealing solution for $x$ in `R`, then, would be something like `-qnorm(0.05/2) * sqrt(4)`.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to first visualize a Normal(10,4) distribution.  What would this distribution look like if we shift it to the left by 10 units?  Where would it be centered?  If we further standardize it by dividing by the standard deviation how would the transformed distribution look?  Since these are all linear operations, what can we say about percentiles from the standard normal distribution in relation to our original normal distribution?